# FOSUserBundle ignore password field

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

So I'm using the FOSUserBundle with LDAP as my authentication method, and I'm wondering whether there is a way to remove/ignore the `password` field for my `FOSUser` entity?

I realize removal might not be ideal (in case it messes with internal logic), but the column is never used, and I'm forced to fill it when I'm creating `FOSUsers` from fixtures:

```
$user = new FOSUser();

$user->setDn($item["dn"]);
$user->setEnabled(1);
$user->setUsername($item["samaccountname"][0]);
$user->setUsernameCanonical(strtolower($item["samaccountname"][0]));
$user->setEmail($item["mail"][0]);
$user->setEmailCanonical(strtolower($item["mail"][0]));
$user->setDepartment($ldap_groups[$matches[1]]);
$user->setDepartmentDn($group);
$user->setPassword('blank'); // Is there away to avoid this?

$manager->persist($user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually remove the password, but you have to keep a `getPassword()` as that is defined in the UserInterface. In case you want to keep it, e.g. when you allow for multiple login types where you will need it again. I recommend setting the field as nullable. If you are using annotations it's as simple as adding `nullable=true` to the column:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="password", nullable=true)
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, the exact syntax is slightly different - [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides) overrides the `BaseUser` field. Directly adding the password field caused duplication errors.

Answer (score 0):

So to override a column doctrine allows for [Inheritance Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="password",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "password",
 *              type     = "string",
 *              nullable=true
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class FOSUser extends BaseUser implements LdapUserInterface
{
  // Extended logic.
}
```

The password field still resides in `BaseUser`, but is overwritten by the `@ORM\AttributeOverride` annotation.